# Retrieve Datafactory ManagedID in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity

I have a nested template to create a `datafactory` and I want to retrieve its managed identity to the master template. However, I'm having a problem using the reference function as shown below.

It expects 1-2 arguments but the online documentation asks to use the format I am using - see image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDDva.png]

Comment: So what is the question? I don't know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the online documentation you are referring to.  Based on your snippet I believe it is because you are using `reference(concat(`it should be`reference(resourceId(` as really you want the actually resourceID.